# Whose Collection interface implementation does kotlin use?

Tags: kotlin

I know that collections like `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, `HashSet` and so on in kotlin are just type aliases for the same collections in java. But what about interfaces like `List` or `Collection` ? According to this [article](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/) kotlin has its own implementation of `Collection` interface which has less members than java's own.

I decided to run this code hoping it didn't get compiled because there is not `stream` method in kotlin's implementation:

```
fun main(){
   val x: Collection<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()
   x.stream()
}
```

but it successfully got compiled.

**So whose collection interface implementation does kotlin use ?** If java's one, why does kotlin have its own implementation then ? But if kotlin's one, how does it use `stream` method which it doesn't have ?

Answer (score 2):

`Collection` is one of those "[mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types)". As the documentation says:

> Kotlin treats some Java types specifically. Such types are not loaded from Java "as is", but are mapped to corresponding Kotlin types. The mapping only matters at compile time, the runtime representation remains unchanged.

As far as *Kotlin* is concerned, the type you are using is `kotlin.collections.Collection`, and there is no `java.util.Collection` (you'll get an error if you try to use the fully-qualified name). It has the `stream` method because it is "mapped to" `java.util.Collection`.

As far as the JVM is concerned, there is only one type `java.util.Collection`.

Exactly how this mapping is implemented is "compiler magic".

See also

```
println(Collection::class.java)
println(Collection::class)
// output:
// interface java.util.Collection
// class kotlin.collections.Collection
```

The same mapping happens with lots of other types. `kotlin.Int` and `java.lang.Integer`, `kotlin.String` and `java.lang.String`, etc.

As for why Kotlin has its own `Collection` type, rather than just an alias of Java's `Collection`, this is because Kotlin doesn't want *exactly* the same interface as Java.

For example, Kotlin's `Collection` is immutable, and there is another `MutableCollection` for mutable collections. This cannot be implemented just an alias. There is only one `Collection` interface in Java, *and* it's mutable.

Another example is that Kotlin wants `size` to be a property, which makes sense, but Java's `Collection` interface has `size()` as a method.

Comment: `The mapping only matters at compile time, the runtime representation remains unchanged.` means that at compile time kotlin uses one type but at run time the other. So if kotlin used `kotlin.collections.Collection`, my program wouldn't get compiled because at compile time there is not `stream` method.

Comment: @VanechikSpace All the APIs in `java.util.Collection` have a corresponding equivalent in `kotlin.collections.Collection`. Most of these mappings look exactly the same, using the [rules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html), so `stream()` maps to `stream()`. Some are different, like how the `size()` method corresponds to the `size` property. That is what a "mapping" is.

Comment: @VanechikSpace in other words, yes there *is* a `stream()` method in `kotlin.collections.Collection`. It is *mapped* from `java.util.Collection.stream()`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers: remember that **the JVM is only one of several compiler targets for Kotlin** — while it was the first and is still probably the most widely-used, there's also [Kotlin for JavaScript](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html), [Kotlin for Android](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/android-overview.html), [Kotlin Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-overview.html), [Kotlin Wasm](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/wasm-overview.html) (experimental), and also [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) which can target more than one of those.

So while Kotlin/JVM [maps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types) its types to JVM ones, **on other platforms they'll map to other types**: existing types on those platforms, or to types included in the relevant runtime.

That is of course one reason why Kotlin has its own types in the first place: **they allow you to write multiplatform code that uses collections**, without having to write them from scratch.

Another is that it allows its own refinements — such as splitting interfaces into read-only and mutable variants (as described in other answers).

Finally, it's probably worth stressing that while it's interesting to learn how the Kotlin platform(s) are implemented, **you shouldn't rely on anything not specified in the official documentation**. (Implementations can change between versions, as they try to improve performance etc.) Similarly, it's usually better to program to the interface, not to the implementation. (For example, if you specify an `ArrayList` type then you're restricted to that particular implementation, while if you specify a `MutableList`, then your code will automatically be able to handle `LinkedList`s, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`s, and/or any other list types on your platform(s) too.)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, the collections like `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, and `HashSet` are indeed just type aliases for the equivalent `Java collections`. However, Kotlin also has its own `collection interfaces` and implementations, which are designed to be more Kotlin-friendly and idiomatic.

When you declare a variable like `val x: Collection<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()` you're using `Kotlin's Collection interface` but initializing it with a `Java ArrayList`. This works seamlessly because Kotlin prioritises `interoperability` with Java.

Now, regarding the `stream()` method: Kotlin's Collection interface doesn't include it, but Kotlin still allows you to use `Java's Stream API` on collections. When you call `x.stream()`, Kotlin covertly converts the Kotlin Collection to a `Java Collection` (in this case, ArrayList) and then invokes the `stream()` method provided by Java's Collection interface.

In a nutshell, Kotlin's collections are designed for Kotlin developers' convenience but don't hinder interoperability with Java. When you use Kotlin collections with Java, Kotlin handles the necessary conversions behind the scenes. It's all about making Kotlin development smoother while not breaking ties with Java when needed.